# Hadoop copyFromLocal: '.': No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I use Windows 8 with a cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.4.2-0 virtual box.

I downloaded a text file as words.txt into the Downloads folder.
I changed directory to Downloads and used `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal words.txt`

I get the `no such file or directory` error.
Can anyone explain me why this is happening / how to solve this issue?

Here is a screenshot of the terminal:

[image: terminal.png]

Someone told me this error occurs when Hadoop is in safe mode, but I have made sure that the safe mode is OFF.

Comment: Where are you trying to copy **to**? Give a destination folder

Comment: I am wanting to copy it to HDFS. My ultimate goal is to run WordCount on this text file.

Comment: I understand that, but to which HDFS folder?

Comment: As I commented previously, you're using CDH, so you can use Hue to upload files to HDFS, if you're not comfortable in the terminal

Comment: I have also used Hue, but I am wanting to learn and become better using the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's happening because `hdfs:///user/cloudera` doesn't exist.

Running `hdfs dfs -ls` probably gives you a similar error.

Without specified destination folder, it looks for `.`, the current HDFS directory for the UNIX account running the command.

You must `hdfs dfs -mkdir "/user/$(whoami)"` before your current UNIX account can use HDFS, or you can specify an otherwise existing HDFS location to copy to

Comment: This resolved the no such file or directory error. But when I run hdfs dfs -ls I get a . instead of words.txt. See: http://i64.tinypic.com/288s56o.png

Comment: That means it was not copied into the user directory, as pointed out. I strongly suggest that you actually specify which folder you are listing or uploading to

Comment: I get it now. I got everything working now. Thank you for your help!